# How to edit json data from multiple sets of key value pair

Tags: java, json

How can we modify json data from multiple data(like value from any key value pair)  in java?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit your question to provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

A "JSON object" is actually an oxymoron. JSON is a text format describing an object, not an actual object, so data can either be in the form of JSON, or deserialised into an object.

Once you have parsed the JSON into a Javascript object (called data in the code below), you can for example access the object for KEY2 and it's properties like this:

```
var obj = data.KEY2;
alert(obj.NAME);
alert(obj.VALUE);
```

If you have the key as a string, you can use index notation:

```
var key = 'KEY3';
var obj = data[key];
```

Comment: Hi! Congrats on posting your first answer. Note that the question was about Java, not JavaScript.